# How To Add Specific Log During Data Flow Task

Tags: sql-server, logging, ssis, etl, ssis-2012

I've made a Data Flow Task in SSIS, which contains 6 components: XML Source, Sort, Row Count, Derived Column, Data Conversion, OLE DB Destination. How could I add logs when execute this Data Flow Task to trace which component the package is going through?

Answer (score 0):

## Executing From Visual Studio

If you are running the package from Visual Studio, after executing the package a `Progress` Tab appear right to the `Control Flow` and `Data Flow` Tab, it contains a full log of the execution.

## Executing Using DTExec

If you are using the [DTExec utility](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms162810.aspx) you can use a similar code to save logs

```
dtexec /f "c:\pkgOne.dtsx" /l "DTS.LogProviderTextFile;c:\log.txt"
```

## Executing from SQL agent Job

From the following [Microsoft article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/ssms/agent/view-sql-server-agent-error-log-sql-server-management-studio) here are the steps:

1. In Object Explorer, click the plus sign to expand the server that contains the SQL Server Agent error log that you want to view.
2. Click the plus sign to expand SQL Server Agent.
3. Click the plus sign to expand the Error Logs folder.
4. Right-click the error log you want to view and select View Agent Log.

## Additional Info

- [Integration Services (SSIS) Logging](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/integration-services/performance/integration-services-ssis-logging)
- [SSIS Logging from SQL Agent job](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/352b2e1c-4962-48bd-a718-d9870512e290/ssis-logging-from-sql-agent-job?forum=sqlintegrationservices)